# jQuery delegate() not working ie IE

Tags: jquery

I have a block of code being generated dynamically using xforms and dojo.

The following block of jQuery works fine in chrome and firefox but not in IE:

> jQuery('.premiumBlock').delegate('.dijitCheckBoxInput', 'click', function(){
>      // do something
>      });

The code will then "do stuff" which is working correctly in chrome and firefox, but not IE.

Nearly everything is created dynamically including the class names.

I have read other similar SO queries where the majority of suggestions have been to change .delegate() to .live() or .on(). These suggestions do not work - it would merely change the ancestor that the event will bubble to.

Any ideas why this may not be working and, more specifically, how I can make it work?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you're clicking on the checkbox and not the label element for the checkbox? Using the click event on checkboxes is often necessary in IE, but an annoying side effect is that it works like a click event--if you don't click the bound element itself, the event won't fire, even if the checkbox changes.

Comment: I meet the same case, on ie8.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
$('#somecontainer').ajaxComplete(function() {
  $(".premiumBlock").delegate(".dijitCheckBoxInputat","click",function() {
        //do something
  });
});
```

This should make it work in IE also